# Best way to do run data analysis queries on more than 50,000 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to pull some stats from a database table which contains more than 50,000 rows, but i have observed that response time is pretty poor.

For example when I ran a simple SQL query with wild card on 50,000 rows, it took nearly 4 minutes time in SQL Server, and I am afraid that if I will run this query from my web application it will take a lot of time.

So, precisely I wanted to ask that what is the best practice run these queries? How can I pull some stats from a table with simple where clauses?

Comment: It shouldn't take that long. 50,000 rows isn't much data. Perhaps something is wrong with your database design and/or your query - or the query is overly complicated. Perhaps you should post a question with the query, the table structures and request help with optimising it.

Comment: 1 important thing which i have observed is that i was trying to run queries on 'ntext' datatype, casting it to nvarchar has improved performance alot.

Comment: Ntext is a datatype that will be deprecated

Comment: Yes i know but can't do much about it, i am not allowed to modify structure of database.

Comment: If you are scanning large text fields, then consider adding a full text index on to the fields.  This could substantially increase performance.